# Assert in silex with defined options

Tags: symfony, silex

Want to assert a function in Silex with some pre-defined slugs. My idea is to have this code, but to have the choice to add in the slug assert some different assertions as 'about-us', 'contact' and 'services'. Any idea?

```
$app->get('/{slug}', function ($slug) use ($app) {

[...]

})
->bind('page')
->assert('slug', 'about-us')
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in the second argument of `assert` method. Add list of available slug values:

```
->assert('slug', 'about\-us|contact|services');
```